# Stuck with JavaScript animation

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

I haven't written code in ages and I have decided to make a fun, little website to refresh my skills. Unfortunately, I am stuck with animating a clay-pigeon (I am making an interactive thingy). I have been stuck on this piece of code for several days now and I can't get my head around it. Any help will be dearly appreciated.

Here's the segment my code where I am stuck:

```js
var uwifh = 1;
if (uwifh == 1) {
    var screenwidth = screen.width-'px';
    var screenheight = screen.height-'px';

    function lanceerklei() {
        var e = document.getElementById('clay');
        e.style.visibility = 'visible';

        var positie_yinit= Math.floor(Math.random*(screenheight/1.7))+50;
        var positie_y;
        var positie_x = 10;
        var paraboolfactor = (Math.floor(Math.random * 50) + 1)/1000;
        var parabooltop = screenwidth/2;
        var snelheid = Math.floor(Math.random*20)+20;

        var elke20ms;
        elke20ms= setInterval(function(){
            positie_x= positie_x += snelheid;
            positie_y= (-1 * paraboolfactor) * (positie_x - parabooltop) ^ 2;
            e.style.left = positie_x + 'px';
            e.style.top = positie_y + positie_yinit + screenheight + 'px';
        }, 20);
    };

    window.setTimeout(lanceerklei, 1000);
};
```

```css
 #clay{
    position: fixed;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.threecountiesclayshoot.co.uk/communities/0/004/013/041/930//images/4619113458.png" id="clay">
```

This is not the entire code If you want the rest, I will give the rest.

Once again any help is appreciated.

Comment: Many issues just to get it to run. Check thi fiddle out https://jsfiddle.net/pL631a3y/ for "working" code.

Comment: There is few odd bits in your code. First `var uwifh = 1;
  if (uwifh == 1){` and this `var screenwidth = screen.width-'px';` is wrong assuming you're aiming for `var screenwidth = screen.width + 'px';` `+` will concat string when `-` will just try to substract.

Comment: More following @GilesC comment, random is a function

Comment: Another thing; Learn how to use the debugger and check the console in the browser you are using. They are invaluable tools to find bugs and see what the result of your operations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two things that are incorrect in your code. First, you cannot use the - operator to slice away 'px' from '100px' for example. If you really want to use `screen.width` (or the height property) there is no need to either since it is a numeric value and not a string to start with, you should just do `var screenwidth = screen.width`.

The second thing is that Math.random is a function and needs to be called like this `Math.random()`.

With those corrections your animation came to some sort of life and I think the remaining work concerns your logic for the animation.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, now I can proceed with the rest of my (weird) creation.